# Add new row at the top of grid without using row indicator

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a button. When I click at it, a new row is added to the gridview and allow a user to edit in that row. How do I make new row appear in the first row?

It looks like the top most row in the following article but not
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument778

Currently, I did like the following code. It works but not good. With this solution, I also have a problem with scroll bar. If grid has many rows, the scroll bar will appear. Grid view will have a little blink when a new row is added because

- it moves focus and scroll to last row -> last row is removed -> new row is added at the top -> move focus and scroll to top row

To disable scroll, I followed the article https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ19190 to create a custom gridview. So far so good. But the problem is I do not want to custom grid. Does anybody have idea?

If I have to custom grid, how can I convert MainView to my custom grid at design mode? 
- in design mode, click on MainView of grid view, then choose convert to ...-> custom grid view does not appear in the menu

Sample code

```
private void AddNewRow(GridView gv) {
gv.AddNewRow();
var row = gv.GetRow(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle);

var helper = new ListDataControllerHelper(gv.DataController);

// Binding list has a method InserAt(index, object), but in my case the object can not be created directly.
// Hence, I do not know what it is. I only get new object through gv.AddNewRow()
// I can work around by extending binding list  
// but grid view does not support adding new row at specific position to adapt with InsertAt or my custom binding list 

// It is not a good idea
helper.BindingList.Remove(row); 
helper.BindingList.Insert(0, row); 
gv.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
gv.SetFocusedRowModified();
}
```

I will appreciate all the help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add a row without your layout being updated automatically, try to suspend and resume the layout like so:

```
gv.SuspendLayout();
helper.BindingList.Remove(row); 
helper.BindingList.Insert(0, row); 
gv.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
gv.SetFocusedRowModified();
gv.ResumeLayout(true);
```

In general, your method of inserting a row seems fine.

Comment: In case Binding list has a method InserAt(index, object), or can be extended AddNewAt(index).
But grid view does not support adding new row at specific position. I have to use View.AddNewRow() to add new row unless all events relevant to adding new row of grid (e.g. InitNewRow) are ignore. Do you know how to use new method of extended binding list without using AddNewRow of grid view?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this question :s. What are you looking for ?